# wileysev document class messes up bmatrix etc. from amsmath

Tags: amsmath, journal-publishing

Consider the following example using `wileysev`document class (used for books by John Wiley, available [in this zip file](http://media.wiley.com/assets/1330/31/latex_macros_7x10.ZIP)):

```
\documentclass{wileysev}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix} 16 & 19 & 30 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

1. I am guessing that this is because of all the fudging around with `\@array...` macros that `wileysev.cls` does.
2. How do I restore the default output of `bmatrix`?
3. Does anyone know the right forum to report this bug to Wiley?

Comment: i haven't yet found a source for the class file, but i have found documentation on line, at http://www.texnology.com/docs.pdf that gives an address for help with the package.  as one of the maintenance group for `amsmath`, i would like to find out more about this problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The source of class file is in the link that I provide in the question.

Comment: well, that was certainly dopey.  thanks.  i'll take a look, but i think it's likely the problem should be reported to the publisher's technical representative.

Comment: The class redefines `array` to add `@{}` fore and aft the column specifications for the environment; since `amsmath`'s code for `matrix` does a similar thing, you end up with reducing too much the space around the array and the delimiters are too close. Imposing a value of `\arraystretch` of 1.25 *could* improve multiline arrays, but it definitely spoils one liners. I'd simply restore the standard definition of `\@array` and the value 1 for `\arraystretch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wileysev` class redefines `array` to add `@{}` fore and aft the column specifications for the environment; since `amsmath`'s code for `matrix` does a similar thing, you end up with reducing too much the space around the `array` and the delimiters are too close. Imposing a value of `\arraystretch` of 1.25 *could* improve multiline arrays, but it definitely spoils one liners. I'd simply restore the standard definition of `\@array` and the value 1 for `\arraystretch`.